# Central autosizing column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

How can I achieve a 3 column layout, where the central column auto-expands for the content but stays central, with the left and right columns shrinking as needed?

I'm told this can be done with flexbox but I can't find an example where this does what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `flex: 1` to the *left* and *right* flex items and `flex: 0 0 auto` (because default is `0 1 auto` and you don't want the `flex-shrink` value to be 1) for the *middle* flex item - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper>* {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
}

.middle {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>left</div>
  <div class="middle">Lorel ipsum</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```